# When I try to create another dialog, my app crashes

Tags: android, crash, dialog

I have made it possible to share content with my app. When this happens, an altertdialog pops up and asks what to do with it. For one of those choices, another dialog shall pop up afterwards. But here's the problem: When I do show();, my app crashes:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:2053)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:2079)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:678)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:632)
        at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:143)
```

Here is how I make the dialog:

```
.subscribe((@NonNull InfoItem result) -> {
    DDialog dDialog = new DDialog();
    dDialog.doSomethingWith(result)
    dDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dDialog");
    finish();
    return;
}, (@NonNull Throwable throwable) -> {
    onError();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`dDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dDialog");` is asynchronous, which means that right after calling `show()` you call `finish();`, which finishes your current activity before your dialog has a chance to show up, and when it does try to show up, the activity is already in an incorrect state

Comment: I removed finish(), but the same error shows up. is it possible that when I create the new dialog, the old one is closed by default?
Or is there a way to pause everything here until the other dialog closes?

Comment: Well, then your activity is in incorrect state because of something else. You can try showing your dialog like this: `FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(dialog, null);
ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();`. But this way you will lose your dialog on rotation